# Problemas em projeto com Maven - Algaworks

Tags: java, maven

Sou iniciante em Maven, estou com alguns probleminhas que não consigo resolver. Alguém sabe decifrar estes erros? Não entendi muito bem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Edite a pergunta com seu Pom.xml

Comment: Estou tentando adicionar o código com Pom.xml, mas só aparece a primeira linha, como adiciono ele todo? Dúvidas na hora de formatar, cliquei em {} pede pra "adicionar o código aqui", mas só aparece a primeira linha.

Comment: ajuda avançada na edição » http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help - e muito melhor do que um screenshot do erro, é você colar o texto do erro aqui; é mais fácil de ler e o Google também agradece

Answer (score 0):

Coloque esse trecho em seu pom.xml:

```
<build>
        <finalName>NomeProjeto</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Em seguida vá na pasta `webapp` crie uma pasta chamada `WEB-INF` e crie o arquivo `web.xml` dentro dessa pasta.

Feito isso clique com o botão direito em seu projeto, vá em `Maven` >  `Update Project` > `OK`